# Predict with pytorch lightning when using BCEWithLogitsLoss for training

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to see how my trained model would predict a single instance of `y` and have of list of predicted and actual `y`.
It seems I'm missing a few steps and I'm not sure how to implement the `predict_step`, here is what I currently have:

```py
mutag = ptgeom.datasets.TUDataset(root='.', name='MUTAG')

train_idx, test_idx = train_test_split(range(len(mutag)), stratify=[m.y[0].item() for m in mutag], test_size=0.25)

train_loader = ptgeom.loader.DataLoader(mutag[train_idx], batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
test_loader = ptgeom.loader.DataLoader(mutag[test_idx], batch_size=32)

class MUTAGClassifier(ptlight.LightningModule):
    
    def __init__(self):
      # The model is just GCNConv --> GCNConv --> graph pooling --> Dropout --> Linear
      super().__init__()
      self.gc1 = ptgeom.nn.GCNConv(7, 256)
      self.gc2 = ptgeom.nn.GCNConv(256, 256)
      self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(256, 1)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index=None, batch=None, edge_weight=None):
      # Note: "edge_weight" is not used for training, but only for the explainability part
      if edge_index == None:
        x, edge_index, batch = x.x, x.edge_index, x.batch
      x = F.relu(self.gc1(x, edge_index, edge_weight))
      x = F.relu(self.gc2(x, edge_index, edge_weight))
      x = ptgeom.nn.global_mean_pool(x, batch)
      x = F.dropout(x)
      x = self.linear(x)
      return x
 
    def configure_optimizers(self):
      optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
      return optimizer

    def training_step(self, batch, _):
      y_hat = self.forward(batch.x, batch.edge_index, batch.batch)
      loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_hat, batch.y.unsqueeze(1).float())
      self.log("train_loss", loss)
      self.log("train_accuracy", accuracy(y_hat, batch.y.unsqueeze(1)), prog_bar=True, batch_size=32)
      return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, _):
        x, edge_index, batch_idx = batch.x, batch.edge_index, batch.batch
        y_hat = self.forward(x, edge_index, batch_idx)
        self.log("val_accuracy", accuracy(y_hat, batch.y.unsqueeze(1)), prog_bar=True, batch_size=32)


checkpoint_callback = ptlight.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    dirpath='./checkpoints/',
    filename='gnn-{epoch:02d}',
    every_n_epochs=50,
    save_top_k=-1)

trainer = ptlight.Trainer(max_epochs=200, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])

trainer.fit(gnn, train_loader, test_loader)
```

Answer (score 1):

The crux here is that you use `F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits` in your `training_step` (for numerical stability I suppose). This means that `nn.Sigmoid` has to be applied to your output both in `validation_step` and `predict_step` as the operation is not part of `forward()`. Check [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/bceloss-vs-bcewithlogitsloss/33586/5) for more information. Notice that you may also need to round your predicted results depending on which accuracy method you are using in order to get correct metric results.

```py
class MUTAGClassifier(ptlight.LightningModule):
    
    def __init__(self):
      # The model is just GCNConv --> GCNConv --> graph pooling --> Dropout --> Linear
      super().__init__()
      self.gc1 = ptgeom.nn.GCNConv(7, 256)
      self.gc2 = ptgeom.nn.GCNConv(256, 256)
      self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(256, 1)
      self.s = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x, edge_index=None, batch=None, edge_weight=None):
      # Note: "edge_weight" is not used for training, but only for the explainability part
      if edge_index == None:
        x, edge_index, batch = x.x, x.edge_index, x.batch
      x = F.relu(self.gc1(x, edge_index, edge_weight))
      x = F.relu(self.gc2(x, edge_index, edge_weight))
      x = ptgeom.nn.global_mean_pool(x, batch)
      x = F.dropout(x)
      x = self.linear(x)
      return x
 
    def configure_optimizers(self):
      optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
      return optimizer

    def training_step(self, batch, _):
      y_hat = self.forward(batch.x, batch.edge_index, batch.batch)
      loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_hat, batch.y.unsqueeze(1).float())
      self.log("train_loss", loss)
      self.log("train_accuracy", accuracy(y_hat, batch.y.unsqueeze(1)), prog_bar=True, batch_size=32)
      return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, _):
        x, edge_index, batch_idx = batch.x, batch.edge_index, batch.batch
        y_hat = self.forward(x, edge_index, batch_idx)
        y_hat = self.s(y_hat)
        y_hat = torch.where(y_hat > 0.5, 1, 0) # may be needed
        self.log("val_accuracy", accuracy(y_hat, batch.y.unsqueeze(1)), prog_bar=True, batch_size=32)

    def predict_step(self, batch, _):
        x, edge_index, batch_idx = batch.x, batch.edge_index, batch.batch
        y_hat = self.forward(x, edge_index, batch_idx)
        y_hat = self.s(y_hat)
        y_hat = torch.where(y_hat > 0.5, 1, 0) # may be needed
        return y_hat
```

You could then do the following in order to get a list of predictions with their corresponding ground truth:

```py
batch = next(iter(train_loader))         # get a batch
y_hat = trainer.predict(your_model, batch)

print(list(y_hat))
print(list(batch.y))
```

Comment: I can't it to work sadly, the x, y = next(iter(train_loader)) part doesn't work on getting a batch. I've tried to work around it but I haven't succeeded in getting a y_hat prediction to get printed.

Comment: next(iter(train_loader))   gives me 

DataBatch(edge_index=[2, 1322], x=[595, 7], edge_attr=[1322, 4], y=[32], batch=[595], ptr=[33])

Comment: have you tried to input the batch? `y_hat = trainer.predict(your_model, batch)`

Comment: it gives me the error saying that 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x' when running y_hat = trainer.predict(your_model, batch)

Comment: I don't know how your dataloader is built. But you could try: `y_hat = trainer.predict(your_model, batch[0])`